# Performance of Scikits NB vs NLTK NB

Tags: machine-learning, nltk, scikit-learn, bayesian-networks, scikits

I have compared the performance of two implementations of Naive Bayes in both NLTK and Scikits (Bernoulli versions, class priors doesn't matter as I am using exactly the same amount of training examples for each class) by plotting their corresponding learning curves for my 3-class problem. X axis is training dataset size (forget about the real values), and Y is accuracy. [Here is](http://i50.tinypic.com/ddlwgl.png) what I got.

Any reason for this difference in performance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NLTK does not implement Bernoulli Naive Bayes. Instead, its [`NaiveBayesClassifier`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/master/nltk/classify/naivebayes.py#L43) uses the multinomial NB decision rule together with boolean features.

While this combination of multinomial and Bernoulli NB parts is actually sometimes recommended (e.g. by [Jurafsky and Manning](https://www.coursera.org/course/nlp) for sentiment analysis), it usually represents the worst of both worlds and is most likely the result of a mistake.